# Terraform - SHA256 hash of bytes that have been base64-encoded

Tags: hash, terraform, base64, sha256

Let's say that I have three null bytes, and I base64-encode them:

(Python)

```
import base64
import hashlib

foo = b'\xd3\x4d\x34'

foo_b64 = base64.b64encode(foo)
print(foo_b64)
# Outputs: 
# 0000

foo_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(foo).hexdigest()
print(foo_sha256)
# Outputs: 
# 0e10e03565f4664a05c3bc63ed35df3e1a9cb2568371db4f12b66c728943f802
```

Let's say I put that base64 string in a Terraform config:

```
locals {
  foo_b64 = "0000"
}
```

In Terraform, I need to find a way to get the SHA256 hash of the **raw** value of `foo`, i.e. in Terraform I need to generate that same hash (`0e10e03565f4664a05c3bc63ed35df3e1a9cb2568371db4f12b66c728943f802`).

I've gone through the Terraform functions and can't seem to find something that works.

- `sha256(local.foo_b64)` gives the SHA256 hash of the base64 string, not the raw bytes that it encodes.
- `sha256(base64decode(local.foo_b64))` throws an error: `Call to function "base64decode" failed: the result of decoding the provided string is not valid UTF-8.`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use Terraform's `base64encode` for the local variable and then `base64decode` should work.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Are you saying I could do `foo_b64 = base64encode("AAAA")`? `base64decode` would work then, sure, but it would just decode back to "AAAA", not the original raw bytes.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I was thinking more along the lines of first encoding whatever that is using Terraform's built-in function rather than providing it the encoded value. But I might find some time to test if your use case would work.

Comment: I just tested using Terraform `base64decode` and `sha256`, no issues. Could it be that the original base64 encoding added some unwanted characters?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the sample code. Try it with the new binary string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terraform language has a string type that is defined as containing Unicode characters rather than bytes, so anything which creates a string from raw input requires that input to be UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters.

This means that it isn't possible in general to pass raw binary data from one function to another. For situations where a Terraform configuration *does* need to work with small binary objects, the convention is to pass them around as base64 encoding, but that works only if your configuration treats the base64 data as opaque, never needing to decode it, because there is no way to represent the decoded form.

Given that, I think in order to solve your underlying problem with Terraform you will need to take a different approach. For example, perhaps whatever external system is generating the base64 string could also generate the SHA256 checksum of it, which Terraform would then also treat as opaque rather than trying to calculate it directly. You've presented one technical solution to an unstated problem here, so I can't be any more specific about what other options might be, but the main requirement would be that Terraform will just pass through the (base64-encoded) binary data verbatim to a provider and never interrogate it directly itself.